# Cannot create resource instance. javax.naming

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi

trying to use tomcat pool to connect to  the database.

Here is my code :

web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
   <description>Resource pour le pool de connexion vers tomcat</description>
   <res-ref-name>jdbc/pool</res-ref-name>
   <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
   <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

context.xml :

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/CompteBancaire">
    <Resource name="jdbc/pool" auth="container" type="javax.sql.Datasource">
        <ResourceParams name="jdbc/pool">
            <parameter>
                <name>username</name>
                <value>marc</value>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <name>password</name>
                <name>marc</name>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <name>driverClassName</name>
                <value>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</value>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
        <name>url</name>
        <value>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</value>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <name>factory</name>
                <value>org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory</value>
            </parameter>
        </ResourceParams>
    </Resource>
</Context>
```

in the constructor of my DAO class :

```
DataSource ds;

//récupération de la source de donnée
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
ds = (DataSource) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/pool");

conn = ds.getConnection();
```

I have an exeption trying to look up^and create the datasource :

```
GRAVE: null
javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
        at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:143)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:304)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:793)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:140)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:781)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:140)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:781)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:140)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:781)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
        at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:152)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
        at cb.model.dao.BankDAONatural.<init>(BankDAONatural.java:35)
        at cb.model.dao.BankDAONatural.getInstance(BankDAONatural.java:42)
        at cb.model.dao.DAOFactory.<init>(DAOFactory.java:31)
        at cb.model.dao.DAOFactory.getInstance(DAOFactory.java:37)
        at cb.control.generalDispatcher.init(generalDispatcher.java:33)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:809)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Thank you. It is probably something I did not get concerning datasources

Answer (score 1):

[ResourceParams are gone](http://www.mail-archive.com/tomcat-user@jakarta.apache.org/msg136360.html)

Comment: that was ironic... your link is dead

Comment: I think EJP means that you have to remove the ResourceParams tag. That should work. Please re-check that you're looking to the proper version of Tomcat's documentation.

Comment: @user690022 @mschonaker sorry fixed the link.